# How to pad list column in cuDF dataframe?

Tags: cudf

I want to implement padding operation to each list after collecting with groupby operation.

The conceptual implementation is like this:

```py
df = cudf.DataFrame({"g": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], "a": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1]})
df.groupby("g")["a"].collect().list.pad(max_length=3, pad_left=True, drop="last", padding_value=-1)
```

expected output:

```
g
1      [1, 2, 3]
2     [-1, 1, 3]
3    [-1, -1, 1]
```

How to do this?

After converting pandas dataframe and applying `np.pad` operation worked, but it seems a bit awkward and slow. Are there any way to do it in cuDF/cuPy?

```py
cudf.from_pandas(
    df.groupby("g")["a"]
    .collect()
    .to_pandas()
    .apply(lambda x: np.pad(x, (max(3 - len(x), 0), 0), constant_values=(-1,)))
)
```

c.f. `.apply()` function to cuDF series of list type raises `NumbaNotImplementedError`.

```
NumbaNotImplementedError: list
```

```py
df = cudf.DataFrame({"g": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], "a": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1]})
df.groupby("g")["a"].collect().apply(
    lambda x: np.pad(x, (max(3 - len(x), 0), 0), constant_values=(-1,))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in [RAPIDS cuDF github repo](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/12471), and I'm just closing the loop.

[Nick Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6066528/nick-becker) shared [this link to NVTabular, which the OP was using, which demonstrates how to pad the list column](https://nvidia-merlin.github.io/NVTabular/main/generated/nvtabular.ops.ListSlice.html?highlight=listslice#nvtabular.ops.ListSlice) using `nvtabular.ops.ListSlice`'s `pad` and `pad_value` parameters.

Comment: True, this problem is more suited for other preprocessing package like NVTabular, however, can I keep this post in case someone want to handle the same processing with cuDF?

Comment: yeah keep it, because i hope this will direct them properly :)